# LaTeX systeme without auto-rearrange

Tags: math-mode, equations, systeme

How can I cancel the auto-rearrange function of `\systeme`? I wrote the following line and got the result I did not want. I want the equation generated to be the exact order as I wrote, in which `t` is the last element.

```
$$\systeme*{2x-y+2z+t=-2,x+y-5t=5}
\leftrightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
    2&-1&2&1&-2\\
    1&1&-5&0&5
\end{bmatrix}$$
```

[[image: 1]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose the order of variables manually, see [section 1.3 of the manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/systeme/systeme_doc_fr.pdf#subsection.1.3).  Also see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,systeme}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \systeme*[xyzt]{2x-y+2z+t=-2,x+y-5t=5}
  \leftrightarrow
  \begin{bmatrix}
    2&-1&2&1&-2\\
    1&1&-5&0&5
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, though I wouldn't have asked this question had I understand what the manual says.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, one could use TABstacks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,amsmath}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\TABbinary
\Matrixstack[r]{2x&-y&+2z&+&t=&{-}2\\x&+y&&-&5t=&5}
\leftrightarrow
\setstacktabbedgap{1em}
\TABunaryLeft
\bracketMatrixstack[r]{
    2&-1&2&1&-2\\
    1&1&-5&0&5
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]